# How to convert .kdbx file to Google Password Manager format?

Tags: passwords, password-management, keepass

I want to move off from KeePass to Google Password Manager. It has an import function which accepts CSV format. Their export format looks like that:

```
name,url,username,password,note
```

What's the best way to convert my .kdbx file into CSV with the above style? KeePass seems to support XSL stylesheets, but I'm not very experienced with that. Another thing is that entry names should be valid URLs (I'm okay with fake data there).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why not export from KeePass as CSV [it seems](https://keepass.info/help/base/importexport.html) that they have such an option

Comment: @YisroelTech I don't have CSV export option. My guess it's for import only

Comment: There should still also be a CSV export option (see picture here https://forums.clickstudios.com.au/topic/15270-importing-keepass-data-into-private-lists/)

Comment: @YisroelTech ok I've found it. Guess I could just use a table processor then

Comment: Yes, any spreadsheet editor